# In JavaScript or Typescript the Class name always return 'Object' after casting of item

Tags: javascript, typescript

I know that how to get a class name in JavaScript by MyClass.constructor.name but my question is why class name always return 'Object' as name after the casting as follows:

```
1. MyClass.name  // return MyClass 
2. var myInstance = myClass.constructor.name; // return MyClass
3. var myCast = <MyClass> item; // item is an object with same properties of MyClass
4. var castName = myCast.constructor.name // return Object
```

As I mentioned in line 4, I get the name of myClass as 'Object' why?
Thanks

Comment: That's not valid Javascript or Typescript in line #4

Comment: yes, I correct it

Comment: Casting is only compile time, in runtime what happens is basically `var myCast =  item`, and as you wrote that `item` is just an object, then it makes sense the the constructor name is `Object`

Comment: I have tested the item with a instance of MyClass but the result was same. var mytest = new MyClass(); 
    mytest = item;  var testName= myTest.constructor.name // return Object

Comment: @Shahramfr the `mytest = item;` line is replacing the `MyClass` instance with whatever `item` is.   If `item` was not created with the `MyClass` constructor then its `constructor` will not be `MyClass`.  No amount of reassignment or casting will fix this.  You can always try something like `mytest = Object.assign(new MyClass(), item)`, but that might be brittle.  You apparently already know that it's a `MyClass`, so why do you need to get the name at runtime?  What's your use-case?

Comment: Thank you for your response, it is interesting that your solution (mytest = Object.assign(new MyClass(), item)) works fine , and return the name of MyClass. but unfortunately the item data will be reset. but I need the data of the item for some wrapper function which I use in my project.

Comment: Why do you need to be able to get the string `"MyClass"` from `item` at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far that I've tested for this problem, the solution of @jcalz which was as follows:

```
var newItem = Object.assign(new MyClass(), item);
newItem.name; // return MyClass without values
```

But this solution return MyClass as name but their values will be reset.
Finally I'have changed a bit of this solution as follow so it works for me:

```
var newItem = Object.assign(MyClass, item); //without new keyword
newItem.name; // return MyClass with all values.
```

Thank you, everyone, for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Casting does not change or replace an object's constructor (or prototype), it only informs the type system that *you* the user know the object meets a contract that the compiler could not otherwise prove.

If casting a variable mutated the underlying object, there would be many problems. Most obviously, frozen objects can't be mutated like that and casting simply wouldn't work with them.

```
class MyClass { }

var myInstance = (new MyClass()).constructor.name;
var myCast = <MyClass> (new MyClass());
var castName = myCast.constructor.name

console.log(myInstance, castName); // prints MyClass, MyClass
```

You're accessing the `.constructor` property, which always returns `Object` for object literals. That is not Typescript-specific:

```js
console.log(({}).constructor);
```

Comment: Thanks, so how can we get the original name? is ther any way?

Comment: What original name? If `item` is an object literal, there isn't one. You can always get a *function's* name, including classes, with `MyClass.name` but that's as close as you can get (does not apply to interfaces).

Comment: In fact, item is an element from array of MyClass which I use it in Angular Ionic project, so I use the item as a parameter to a function, like a delete function and in this function I would like to get name of MyClass by item. but it is not possible.

Comment: If `item` was an instance of `MyClass`, the cast would not erase the constructor name.